# Google Data Login to YouTube?

Tags: c#, youtube, gdata

How do I login/logout from youtube using GData in C#? Would it be faster to create a browser instance and display the video with the page or is there a way to embed it straight into your app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the .NET client library (http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) then it will take care of authenticating for you when needed using the credentials you provided:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Authentication

When using the GData API there's no explicit logout method, you can invalidate your token but it will also expire after some time if you don't use it.
Specific details on how to invalidate the token differ according to the authentication mechanism adopted (OAuth, AuthSub, ClientLogin).